# find a key value from a array of objects and render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Data :

```
 const zones =  [
       {
          "ID":"4131",
          "RID":"f1438b",
          "Name":"Hero"
       },
       {
          "ID":"6266",
          "RID":"cd074d",
          "Name":"Villan"
       }
    ]
```

My Code :

```
<Polygon positions={}>
        <Popup>
         {poly.ID}
        </Popup>
</Polygon>
```

Where, poly.ID is "4131".

I need to display Name instead of poly.ID. And Name is obtained from the above Data, where poly.ID is mapped to get the Name.

I tried,

```
<Polygon positions={}>
        <Popup>
         {zones.map((zone) => poly.ID === zone.Name)}
        </Popup>
</Polygon>
```

But it, doesn't seem to render Name nor nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find one element and display its name, here is how you can do :

`zones.find(x => x.ID === poly.ID).Name`

Note I am using `find`, not `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong condition in your map function, you are checking ID against name which will always be false, try this:

```
<Polygon positions={}>
        <Popup>
         {zones.map((zone) => poly.ID === zone.ID)}
        </Popup>
</Polygon>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
<Polygon positions={}>
        <Popup>
         {zones.filter((zone) => poly.ID === zone.ID)[0].Name}
        </Popup>
</Polygon>
```

Answer (score 1):

zones.find(x => x.ID === poly.ID) might return undefined if no match is found. You can add a check like this:

```
const zone = zones.find(x => x.ID === poly.ID);

<Polygon positions={}>
        <Popup>
         {zone && zone.Name}
        </Popup>
</Polygon>
```